# Generate unique address to controller using Spring MVC 4

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a softwares using Spring MVC 4 that I call a controller but for each client I need to put a unique address to this specific client so he can access and only he will know this unique address and for other clients I need more unique address to be able to access the controller.

For example,

I have this simple controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/process")
    public String getProcessPage(){
        return "process";
    }
```

In this case when I call `http://localhost:8080/my-software/process.html` I get my `process.jsp` page but I want to be able to generate a different address with a key or a group of characters for a specific client, for example, for the client A he needs to call `http://localhost:8080/my-software/process776578GSGSHS223.html` and then he gets the page, if he calls only the `/process.html` he won't be able to access anything.

Is it possible to do with Spring MVC 4? Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: how about `process/<secret>.html`. This would be easier to implement as you can accept `<secret>` as a path variable and can validate inside your controller.

Comment: To generate secure Strings, check out SecureRandom() class. You can then put that string as your secret value.